# How do I serve my index.html file while using PHP Slim REST Api?

Tags: php, html, rest, web-applications, slim

I'm getting started with PHP Slim, I'm creating a REST API, and I'd like to put a client in front of that.

It's a simple question, but I can't figure out how to serve my index.html (the client's home page).

I'm starting my slim app using the command in the Slim tutorial: `php -S localhost:8888 -t api index.php`, but I get a 404 when I get a try to navigate to index.html.

I know I can render a `home` state in Slim which serves index.html, but is there another way to do it that doesn't have my API serve a template? In other words, is there a way I can navigate directly to my client?

```
api
  index.php
public
  index.html
```

And currently I'm using the command, `php -S localhost:8888 -t api index.php` to start my server

Comment: Provide the content of the index.html though a route.

Comment: @jmattheis yeah  I know I can do this, but doesn't this tie my api into a specific client? What if I want another client to use my api, which doesn't have the same index.html?

Comment: What do you mean with `client`?

Comment: @jmattheis So for example, 2 different frontend applications. Basically I want to prevent my API from knowing anything about a `client`, including the fact that the client has a index.html.

Comment: @jmattheis so like in this repo, for example, we are able to freely swap out the `client` directory/code which has its own `index.html`. The server directory then has its `index.php` but notice how `index.php` does not serve .html. I'm wondering how that happens

Comment: how do you wanna access the html file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you setting you document root to `/api` so there is actual no way to access the html file without using php code for including the html file. Because the file is before the document root (`/api`)

In my opinion the best option would be to add a route in slim for that and include the index.html from the client in it and then show it

```
$app->get('/clientindex', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $file = '../public/index.html';
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        return $response->write(file_get_contents($file));
    } else {
        throw new \Slim\Exception\NotFoundException($request, $response);
    }
})
```

You could also do something like this:

```
/api
    /index.php // do slim stuff
index.html // display client
```

When you then start the php server with out the file and path `php -S localhost:8888`

the client could be accessed with `domain.com/` and the api with `domain.com/api/`

*Note: you should use the php server only for testing and not in production.*